# Why $ (\operatorname{Im}\varphi)_x=\operatorname{Im}(\varphi_x) $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I don't understand the following fact (from Lemma 2.16 of Qing Liu ''Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves'').

> Let $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ be sheaves (of Abelian groups) on $X$, $\varphi\colon\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ a morphism. We have $ (\operatorname{Im}\varphi)_x=\operatorname{Im}(\varphi_x) $ (for all $x\in X$) and $\operatorname{Im}\varphi$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$.

I already know $ (\operatorname{Im}^p\varphi)_x=\operatorname{Im}(\varphi_x) $ (for all $x\in X$) and $\operatorname{Im}^p\varphi$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$ (where $\operatorname{Im}^p\varphi$ is a presheaf which sends open subset $U$ to $\operatorname{Im}\varphi(U)$), and let $F'$ be a sheafification of presheaf $F$ then $F_x\cong F'_x$ for all $x\in X$.

(And how about cokernel ?)

Comment: You are giving the answer: $(Im\varphi)_x \simeq (Im^p\varphi)_x$ as sheafification doesn't change stalks and $(Im^p\varphi)_x \simeq Im(\varphi_x)$ as you stated.

Comment: @Dominique Mattei Then how can we conclude that isomorphism is identity map?

Comment: It is not the identity map, it is just a canonical isomorphism which allows to use the symbol $=$ instead of $\simeq$, but it is an abuse of notation.

Comment: @Roland Then how do we justify the part '''subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$''? And how can we prove this important fact?: ''sequence of sheaves is exact if and only if exact on the stalks''.

Comment: strictly speaking, if you define the image sheaf as the sheafification of the image presheaf, it won't be a subsheaf of the target. But you have a canonical injection $\operatorname{Im}\varphi\to\mathcal{G}$ and this is only through this canonical injection that the image sheaf is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: @Roland Well you mean $\operatorname{Im}' \varphi:=\operatorname{Im}^p(\operatorname{Im}\varphi\to\mathcal{G})$ is ''true'' image sheaf? This is indeed subpresheaf of $\mathcal{G}$, but first of all, is this a sheaf? And what do you think about the ''important fact''? I think this can't be proven as far as disguising $=$ with $\cong$.

Comment: Is what you defined $\operatorname{Im}'\varphi$ is a sheaf since it is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Im}\varphi$ which is a sheaf. What is important in all of this is that in sheaf theory, as everything rooted in category theory, all universal constructions are only defined up to a unique isomorphism.